# I'm trying to train my X_train and y_train but there is something Array dimesional issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Im trying to train the (X_train and y_train) on line 3) but its giving me error

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[56. 55. 45. 22. 49. 46. 23. 55. 21. 28. 62. 61. 54. 25. 47. 18. 27. 60. 50. 19. 26. 25. 52. 18.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Comment: Please do not put unnecessary numbering before your code (edited).

Comment: The error message literally tells you what to do, did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(-1,1))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train,(-1,1))
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```